# Invoking Reporting Service from Flex using URLRequest and passing credentials using Basic Authorization

Tags: apache-flex, sql-server-2008, ssl

I am trying to invoke an SSL based Report server url from within a flex application. I cannot enable Anonymous authentication due to SQL 2008 R2 RS. I am passing credentials with the header by adding Authentication Basic encoded(uname:pwd) header.

The first call that goes out as post comes back with a valid response and my toolbar on top of reports show up fine. But the subsequent calls that the report server url makes internally to get style sheet and the main content etc goes out without the Authentication header, so I get a response back with Unauthorized and user is prompted to enter uname/pwd again.

Is there way to keep the credentials in the session.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to send the credentials with every request.

**Edit**

So I assume your call opens a new window (HTML) where your report will be rendered.

The credentials for Basic Authorization is requested once by the browser first, it keeps it on memory and sends it for you on the next requests.

Try opening a new window and setting the credentials to the browser first, not to the request. Call your link and the browser will take care of that for you.

Comment: The subsequent calls are not made by Flex. It is the report viewer that calls other pages using GET - like css etc. The Flex application makes one call to the reporting service.